# Dapper Read SqlHierachyId Column (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dapper

I'm trying to read from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database that contain columns of the SQL Server `hierarchyid` type (aka [SqlHierachyId](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlhierarchyid.aspx)).

I want to use this this class with Dapper:

```
public class Foo 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SqlHierarchyId Path { get; set; }
}
```

eg: `connection.Query<Foo>("select 3 as [Id], hierarchyid::Parse('/1/2/3/') as [Path]");`

(Note for Testing, you need to reference  `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` to be able to use SqlHierarchyId)

If I run this, I get a DataException exception: `Error parsing column x (Path=/1/2/3/ - Object)`

I've tried adding an ITypeMap via and setting breakpoints on all the interface methods to see what values it gets passed - but it never gets called.

Any suggestions on how I can get Dapper to let me specify a custom mapper? (Alternatively, if there's an extension that supports all the Sql types, that'd be good too)

Comment: Because it is a general purpose ADO.NET tool, and to minimise dependencies, dapper currently has no provision for this. I'm open to suggestions on good ways of handling it, but: the code to do it does not currently exist in dapper

Comment: Perhaps if I could inject was some way to intercept deserializing based on the type of the property? I honestly thought that's what ITypeMap was supposed to let me do, and I was just too dumb to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dapper 1.34 has support for `SqlHierarchyId` in the core library; it should now just work.

Answer (score 4):

Dapper does support SqlHierarchyId but you will still get the exception if you are using the latest `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` Nuget package.  To make it work, add this to your web.config or app.config:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```